# Progress bar circle on js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

Написал скрипт, для круглого прогресс бара с помощью `SVG`, на чистом `js`.
Но не учел тот факт, что мне нужно еще и текст внутри этого круга сделать. Поискал в инете, и не нашел.
 А вот сделать с обычными div'ами у меня не получается. Не получается  начинать прогресс с определенной точки и заканчивать соответственно тоже в определенной точке.

Вот мой код, который с svg:

```js
function setProgress(percent) {
  const circle = document.getElementById(`circle`);
  const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
  const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;

  circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference;
  const offset = circumference - percent / 10 * circumference;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}
setProgress(7);
```

```css
.svg_circle_loader {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}

.circle_loader {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFB10A;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .5s;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg_circle_loader" width="200" height="200">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" class="circle_loader" id="circle"></circle> <!-- #74563F -->
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как-то так?

```js
const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * circle.r.baseVal.value;
circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} 1000`;

function setProgress(percent) {
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference * (1 - percent / 100);
  pct.innerHTML = percent.toFixed(0) + '%';
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function draw(t) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
  setProgress((t/100)%100)
}
```

```css
.circle_loader {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFB10A;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

text {
  dominant-baseline:middle;
  text-anchor:middle;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg_circle_loader" width="200" height="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" class="circle_loader" id="circle"></circle>
  <text x="100" y="100" id="pct" ></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: У меня почему-то она не так плавно переходит. Это первая проблема. А вторая: как к примеру передать в функцию число 8, и заполняющая линия(желтая) дошла до 8 из 10? Можете подсказать?

Comment: Хотя первую  я уже решил. Осталось вторую решить)

Comment: @Евгений моя функция принимает % от 0 до 100, соответственно для того чтобы получить 1/8 круга надо передать 80

Comment: А как сделать чтоб отсчет был от нуля и до 10, а не до 100? И к примеру передать значение и чтоб функци на этом и остановилась, чтоб не начиналась заново как у вас?

Comment: @Евгений моя начинается заново, потому что тестовая функция мотает входные аргументы в зависимости от времени, т.е. бесконечно по кругу, отвечая на вас первый вопрос - в коде надо поделить на 10 а не на 100 `(circumference * (1 - percent / 10))`

Comment: Ага.. разобрался. спасибо