# Как закрасить только половину рамки?

Tags: html, css

Создаю сайт, решил сделать вот такой интересный показатель:

[image]

Как закрасить только половину рамки?

Comment: А что значит "только половину одной стороны" ?) Чем оно должно отличаться от картинки?

Comment: вопрос не понятен

Comment: Вот , видишь зелёную чуть-закруглёную полоску ? Надо закрасить нижнюю её половину

Comment: Делаешь что-то типа того https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205652/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-in-css и циферблат сверху. Но тогда у линий не будет скругления. Либо попробовать позиционировать прямоугольники и скривлять их, но это извращение мне кажется

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1005070/188366

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/965104/188366

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Progress bar circle on js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005069/progress-bar-circle-on-js)

Comment: Да , спасибо , я делаю это , скругления я добавил с помощью четырёх маленьких кружков расположенных по 4-ём сторонам

Answer (score 1):

**Внимание:** Это решение для данной задачи, но не полноценный ответ на вопрос.
Прошу понять это и не судить строго.

```css
.circle {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 15px solid grey;
 border-left-color: lightgreen;
 border-top-color: yellow;
 border-right-color: red;
 background-color: grey;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  
</div>
```